# How do I edit my home address for Google Now/Maps/Latitude?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, google-latitude, google-now

I just upgraded to the Galaxy Nexus. In the new Google Now, the traffic for my home destination is listed incorrectly. I also noticed that the Home address for myself under the People listing is incorrect. If I try to edit my local profile, there is no field for address. Long pressing on the address only allows me to copy it.

How can I update my Home address?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Update May 3rd, 2015:

My previous answer was for a much outdated platform (latitude doesn't even exist anymore as far as I can tell). Here are some steps for current Google Maps.

1. Open the Maps application.
2. Navigate to Settings.
3. There should be an option to *Edit home or work address*.

Previous answer below for historic purposes...

I finally figured out how to do this and thought I would explain (since it is not very obvious).

1. Open up Google Maps or Latitude
2. Click on yourself (the tag that shows your name, last update time, and city)
3. You should be able to click a `Location history` option
4. With the history open, click the settings button in the lower right corner
5. There are options to change your home and work addresses!

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 4):

On my Android 4.3.1:

- Open **Maps** from your phone
- Pull the menu
- Select **Settings**
- **Edit home or work**

Comment: This should float up to be accepted as it more modern

Comment: I edited my original answer to include new instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Easier solution:

- Click the button on the top left next that says "Maps"
- Select "My Places"
- There is the button for "home"
- Tap and hold to get the option to edit it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but didn't see the described GUI on my Galaxy S3. So here's how I did it:

1. Opened up Google Maps
2. If on the routes/navigation screen, hit the back button until you return to the default map view with a search bar up top.
3. The search bar should have 2 icons on the right: one for routes/navigation, and one that looks like a user icon. Click the user icon.
4. The screen should now have your full name up top, your user image next to the number of reviews you've written, and directly below that, your home and work addresses. **Tap and hold** on the address you want to edit.
5. A new screen should appear with a search box up top, but there should be a home or work icon on the very left of the search box. Simply type or search for your correct address and then hit "Done."

## Alternate Method

1. Again, open up Google Maps and hit the "back" button, if needed, to return to the default maps view.
2. Hit the "menu" button on your phone or just tap the little menu tab at the lower left corner. This should cause a menu to slide out from the left.
3. Tap the "Settings" option and then tap "Edit home or work".
4. Then simply **tap** on the one you want to edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to do this on a desktop, you can go to [maps.google.com](http://maps.google.com), login with your Google account and click `My Places` on the left. This shows your current Home and Work address along with a little location history, and you can find `Edit` under the dropdown menu next to each entry.

Comment: A more direct link:
https://maps.google.com/maps/myplaces hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

July 19th, 2015 (on PC via Google Chrome)

1) Navigate to [maps.google.com](http://maps.google.com)

2) In the search bar, type "home".  Your current saved address will appear below.

3) Click [edit] and fill in your new address.  Then click [Save] or press [Enter].

I was getting frustrated with seeing how far away everything was from my last house!

Answer (score -1):

What about going to http://contacts.google.com, log in, and then edit the information about yourself ? In particular, you can edit your postal address and indicate it as your home address.

Comment: Nope, Google Now/Places/Latitude takes the home location from the option [described in Andy's answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/25287/440)